# Embedded Jetty reads two application contexts

Tags: spring, embedded-jetty

I'm trying to deploy a war file with an embedded Jetty. You can clone a minimal working example here: https://github.com/guilty/jetty-test

When you build the project and try to run the `war-project` with a jetty-runner (which can be downloaded here: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty/jetty-runner/9.2.10.v20150310), everything works fine.

As you can see, I have a `jar-project`, which has a dependency to `war-project` (with `classes` classifier). It tries to start an embedded Jetty server and deploy the `war-project`, but problem is, it reads the application-context.xml twice. As I understand, it finds it twice in the classpath: once in a built *.war, and once in a dependency I made with `classes` classifier.

The same happens if you use `jetty-runner` and call `Runner.main(new String[] { "path-to.war" })`, though as I said before, it works fine when called from command line.

So my question, I guess, is how to restrict classpath to Jetty, if that's at all possible.

As I mentioned, this is a minimal working example, not a real-world application. If I can be of any assistance -- please let me know.

*Edit: I've been asked to put relevant code here, because links may rot.*

Since I won't post all the code, I'm going to describe the situation. I have a *.war project, which is a standard web application powered by spring. It has a class, which throws an exception if more than one instance of it is created by spring (which should never happen, since it's scope is singleton).

Another project references the `war-project` with a `classes` classifier (i.e. gets everything that lays in `src/main/java` and `src/main/resources`) and tries to deploy the war-file produced by `war-project`. Here is the relevant deployment code:

```
Server server = new Server(8080);
WebAppContext webAppContext = new WebAppContext(args[0], "/");

server.setHandler(webAppContext);

server.start();
```

This code runs, but the server fails to start, because a second instance of the bean I wrote about before gets created and it throws an exception.

web.xml of the `war-project`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         version="2.5">

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:application-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
</web-app>
```

application-context.xml of the `war-project` contains only one bean, with default (singleton) scope and nothing else.

Here's the relevant `pom.xml` part of `jar-project`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.guilty.jettyTest</groupId>
        <artifactId>web-project</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <classifier>classes</classifier>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: please post the relevant code here.  links can rot, leaving the question and answer useless at a later date

Comment: @MartinSerrano: the code is really simple and I didn't want to put all of the code in the question, so I only put the most critical parts (which too, are dead simple). I hope it's clearer now.